# What is the close category for questions that ask to write code for an assignment (e.g. print prime numbers)

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

What is the appropriated cagory for voting to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533428/create-a-program-that-will-display-the-first-150-prime-numbers)  question?

Summary:

- Title: Create a program that will display the first 150 Prime Numbers
- Code Provided: no

Comment: When somebody tries to outsource a coding task, I personally go with "too broad". There are many valid approaches and making all of them will take too long. Also, it's not a *specific* problem they have "I've no idea what to write" is not about being stuck on a problem but not even doing anything about the problem. "Unclear" is also valid. Although, do note that not every "I don't know how to code this" is an outsourcing request - some users have put in the research but lack some specific knowledge or concept to make it themselves.

Comment: Homework are not a sign of bad or a close reason. We have enought close reason to cover them. We don't wan't to dillute our vote and flag in too many reason. I don't see a case where we have no other close reason eligible. That we have to use an "It's homework!!!".

Answer (score 14):

Either "**unclear what you're asking**" (since it is not actually asking a question), or "**too broad**" (since it's asking for someone to do the entire project/assignment).

Don't overthink it. The specific reason that you choose is less important than getting the question closed.

Comment: Also include a comment. It isn't entirely clear for the poster from the close reasons that such questions are not okay here.

Comment: I am not a big advocate of comments accompanying close votes. In the vast majority of cases, I would prefer that people vote *instead* of leaving a comment. I don't really think that a project assignment, set entirely in bold, with no question mark in sight is really something people think might be acceptable here.

Comment: Could we have "Missing code sample" or "Example solution missing" category?

Comment: @tymtam We do: it is (inexplicably) hidden under the "off-topic" category. It's the one that begins: "Questions seeking debugging help...", and goes on to talk about lacking a MCVE/MCE/MVE/RepRex/MMCVIII. It isn't really appropriate in this case, though, since the question isn't asking for debugging help. You don't need sample code to answer the question. What you're actually looking for is a "lacks minimum effort" close reason, but that doesn't exist.

Comment: That these types of questions are clearly not suited for SO, yet there are multiple overlapping close categories has always bothered me. Especially after seeing the results of the "3 close vote" experiment. My gut says that the majority of the results that didn't reach consensus is precisely because of this which indicates that going forward, this answer isn't going to be specific enough. There needs to be a clear, single reason or a new "homework" specific close choice.

Comment: Except that homework questions are not off-topic, @Michael. This is problematic because it is not a question, not because it's homework.

Comment: Homework is definitely the wrong word. To clarify what I mean by homework, I mean all the class of questions that fall under “how do I write/solve this?” No code or attempt is given. Due to the categories I frequent, these tend to be homework assignments. However, they also are beginners that don’t know how to begin approaching “new thing X.” I’m not sure what one word summary best describes these, but I believe my original point of multiple overlapping close reasons still stands. I hope it makes sense why I’m not satisfied that there isn’t a specific close reason for these questions.

Comment: I understood your primary concern, @Michael, and I sympathize with it. The problem is coming up with a good summary that describes these types of questions, and ensuring it is something that can't be readily abused (either out of malice or ignorance) to close questions merely because they're homework or merely because the asker was judged not to have met the completely arbitrary "sufficient effort" bar. If you've ideas, post a [[meta-tag:feature-request]]. I've spent some time thinking about it in the past, and don't really have any good ideas. (Well, I still want "not a real question" back…)